# Is deliberate cross posting allowed?

Tags: discussion

We've had two questions recently that were flagged for cross posting with SciFi.  The examples are:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24751/guy-comes-back-to-life-to-watch-his-own-murder-investigation

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/vampire-stake-prevention

Is cross posting between sites allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To a degree, cross posting should be allowed.  There is a [related post on meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931/cross-posting-on-stackexchange-sites?s=2%7C0.9304) which I repeat here:

> Cross posting is fine, provided:
>
> - You respect the differences in the audiences at the different sites;
> - You allow some time to pass between successive questions, and update them in the light of >- the answers previously received; and
> - Really the first point again, you should have an idea what the new site offers in terms of expertise to crack your question that the previous site did not.
>
> Usenet-style forum spamming is, I hardly need to say, bad.

To be honest, I don't see any reason why, if you do not get a decent answer to a question on one site, you should be prevented from asking the question here.

Using these guidelines, I therefore closed the Vampire stake prevention as it was posted 4 minutes later here than on SciFi.  The other question was posted several days apart, and has no answer on SciFi, so I've declined to close this one.

Comment: *"To be honest, I don't see any reason why, if you do not get a decent answer to a question on one site, you should be prevented from asking the question here."* - Meh, I'm not sure this couldn't also be solved by just asking for migration of the question, as otherwise both exact same questions will develop answers on their own over time while only making sense in a merged way. So as long as we don't have "interlinked" questions, I'm not sure you use case is a proper scenario either.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - *I'm not sure you use case is a proper scenario either* - I'm not sure I understand what you mean here.  What use case are you referring to?  Not getting a good answer to a question on one site?

Comment: On the rest of your comment, we're not integrated with SciFi & Fantasy, there's probably several questions that are essentially duplicates anyway, and its unlikely we would have any intention of managing and merging duplicates between two sites that have overlapping scope. This kind of scope gerrymandering has been specifically ruled out between sites in SE.  So on the specific question of the examples here, what would you propose?

Comment: I know, I don't propose this either. Accidental cross-posts by different users always happen and there's no problem with them. The use case I meant was when a user doesn't find an answer on one site and after some time decides to post his very own question again on another site. You proposed this as a valid case for cross-posting and I would say it could as well be solved by an explicit migration request from this very user.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I kind of see this, but the user wants an answer and is maximizing the chance of getting one if they leave it also on the original site.  That (of course) could also be true of simultaneous cross-posts, so my position is hardly perfect - but reflects the guidance from the meta post.

Comment: Hmm, that meta post also seems to lay some emphasis on tailoring the individual questions to the specific communities/scopes of the respective sites, not so much about posting exact same copies. But well, I'm also not completely convinced of either site enough to downvote this idea either. And if we can snatch some good questions from SciFi this way, well. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - and I don't disagree with that, really the OP and editors should make the most of the question by tailoring for the community here.  However in the case questions about SciFi Movies and TV - the question can often be left unchanged.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I've discussed the no-cross-post debates over the months and I think ultimately, the real underlying problem is this: The SE Network was not designed for duplicate questions across sites. With the way it features questions from different sites, if it didn't discourage cross posting  (even when the question is very much on topic in both places), we would see duplicate questions featured on the front page, and that looks weird. The whole "It's ok IF you tailor your question to each site" originally came from Jeff Atwood himself, and that solves the duplicate issue.

Comment: The accepted policy on most of the network is not the answer you cite (why did you choose that particular answer?) but the [answer with very strong support in terms of votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) on the thread that the thread you cite is closed as a duplicate as, which starts with “NO”. Sites can choose to differ, I don't see why [scifi.se] and [movies.se] shouldn't follow the general rule.